# Django Redirect Shortcut

Tags: python, django

Im trying to issue a redirect using the redirect shortcut but Im getting the following error

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("The included urlconf %s doesn't have any patterns in it" % self.urlconf_name)
ImproperlyConfigured: The included urlconf webtools.urls doesn't have any patterns in it
```

My urls.py file looks like this :

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from django.shortcuts import redirect

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
 url(r'^.*$', redirect(macmonster.views.home)),
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url patterns seems a little odd, try:

```
url(r'^(.*)$', redirect('macmonster.views.home')),
```

Comment: I now get ---> NameError: name 'macmonster' is not defined (??)

Comment: You need to import your "macmonster" app or use quotes

Comment: Django can't find your app. Are you sure `macmonster.views.home` is the correct "path" to your view?

Comment: Not sure what version of Django you're using, but the redirect shortcut is deprecated. If you're using 1.3 or later, the GenericView is the preferred method. Something like url(r'^(.*)$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/relativePathUriForHomeView')),

Comment: anoter way is to use `redirect_to({'url': 'path/to/homepage'})`

Comment: Im currently using 1.3. Though when using the following it works. But it would be great if I could just add a view instead of a url..
--> url(r'^(.*)$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/', permanent=False),  name='index'), <--

Comment: But why do you want to redirect to a view? You can just use `url(r'^(.*)$', 'macmonster.views.home'),`

Comment: Because when you dont redirect it allows someone to use an url of say.... mydomain.com/abc123 to get to the view. And I want to ensure that they can only get to the view using the url /.
Thanks

Comment: But then you have to redirect to an url. You can reach a view from different urls, and a view does not have an url attached to it. Therefore you have to use `redirect_to({'url': '/'})`